# How to get bounce animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

How do I achieve the bounce animation similar to the one on macOS dock when an application needs attention and it bounces on the dock. SwiftUI seems to only have ease-curves and spring, which don't really emphasize the way a bounce does.
I've attempted various spring animations and combinations of ease curves and timingCurves to try and get the bounce animation working but nothing really did the job.

The closest to a bounce animation is interpolating spring but the main problem with these animations is that they overshoot during the animation, whereas bounce animations don't.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var bounce = false
    @State private var initialVelocity:Double = 1
    @State private var damping:Double = 1
    @State private var stiffness:Double = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle().fill(Color.red).frame(width:50,height:50)
            .offset(y: bounce ? 0 : -80)
                .animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: self.stiffness, damping: self.damping, initialVelocity: self.initialVelocity))

            HStack(){
                Text("stiffness")
                Slider(value: $stiffness, in: 0...100)
            }
            HStack(){
                Text("damping")
                Slider(value: $damping, in: 0...100)
            }
            HStack(){
                Text("initialVelocity")
                Slider(value: $initialVelocity, in: 0...100)
            }
            Button("Animate" ){
                self.bounce.toggle()
            }
        }.padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for is a bounce animation that replicates gravity, it's a pretty common animation that is available in a lot of games and software
[image]

Answer (score 13):

What's about `.interpolatingSpring(...)`?
Consider the following example but keep in mind, that you might have to play around with the values for `stiffness`, etc.:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var test = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Animatable")
            .offset(y: test ? 0 : -80)
            .animation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 350, damping: 5, initialVelocity: 10))
            
            Button(action: {self.test.toggle()}) {
                Text("Animate")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've tried that many times and the main problem is that the animation overshoots. Whereas bounce animation mimics gravity and bounces to a complete stop at the bottom. Any way to get that in SwiftUI? I'm pretty sure that was something possible in UIKit, or at least there were countless libraries that allowed it.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure whether there is a way to get that in SwiftUI or not. But did you try the other parameters of ```interpolatingSpring(...)```? Full declaration: ```static func interpolatingSpring(mass: Double = 1.0, stiffness: Double, damping: Double, initialVelocity: Double = 0.0) -> Animation```

Comment: Answer is way different what questions asks for. Another problem you have to manually change state of variable to bring the target back to original position

Answer (score 5):

Using multiple offsets, delays and easing I was able to get fairly close to replicating that specific animation.

[image: Demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var bounceHeight: BounceHeight? = nil

func bounceAnimation() {
    withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.3).delay(0)) {
        bounceHeight = .up100
    }
    withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.04).delay(0)) {
        bounceHeight = .up100
    }
    withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.3).delay(0.34)) {
        bounceHeight = .base
    }
    withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.2).delay(0.64)) {
        bounceHeight = .up40
    }
    withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.2).delay(0.84)) {
        bounceHeight = .base
    }
    withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.1).delay(1.04)) {
        bounceHeight = .up10
    }
    withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 0.1).delay(1.14)) {
        bounceHeight = .none
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("☝️")
            .font(.system(size: 200))
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.2)
            .lineLimit(1)
    }
    .padding(8)
    .frame(width: 72, height: 72)
    .background(.purple.opacity(0.4))
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous))
    .shadow(radius: 3)
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
            .stroke(.purple, lineWidth: 2)
    )
    .offset(y: bounceHeight?.associatedOffset ?? 0)
    .onTapGesture {
        bounceAnimation()
    }
}
}

enum BounceHeight {
case up100, up40, up10, base
var associatedOffset: Double {
    switch self {
    case .up100:
        return -100
    case .up40:
        return -40
    case .up10:
        return -10
    case .base:
        return 0
    }
}
}
```